# HTTP POST request to PHP server with the signup details encrypted as HTTP parameters

Tags: iphone

How to post HTTP POST request to PHP server with the signup details encrypted as HTTP parameters. Can you post me a sample code for my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ASIHTTPRequest` and you can it like this:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:someUrl];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"..." forKey:@"user"];
[request setPostValue:@"..." forKey:@"password"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsyncrhonous];
```

There are delegate methods for request like request is finished or failed as

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
   NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
   NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);
}
```

You can always download the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) and can visit [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) too for any further help.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSString *req;


    req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name=%@&Password=%@",userName,pass];// userName and pass are string

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [req dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Below is a delegate which will bring data

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
NSError *erro;
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&erro];

NSLog(@"your data in dictionary is = %@",jsonData);

}
```

hope this will help you !!!